# Policy violation: false positive

Tags: sql-server, admin, sql-server-2016

I've a strange issue with Policy Management in SQL Server 2016.

Background: I had issues with DatabaseMail after patching (see [FIX: SQL Server 2016 Database Mail does not work on a computer that does not have the .NET Framework 3.5 installed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3186435/fix-sql-server-2016-database-mail-does-not-work-on-a-computer-that-doe)). I solved that.

The issue was detected by random. So I decided to use a policy to create a log entry at least.

1. The condition that should be equal to 0:

   ```
   ExecuteSql('Numeric', 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems WHERE sent_status IS NOT NULL AND sent_status <> ''sent'';')
   ```
2. A scheduled system policy was set up.
3. Finally there is an alert watching for type "SQL Server event alert" reporting error number 34052.

Everything fine so far. If I evaluate the policy manually, it's fine. **But** if the policy is evaluated by the job agent a policy violation is reported. Why that?

The job agent, which is created automatically, has 2 steps:

1. Verify that automation is enabled.

   ```
   IF (msdb.dbo.fn_syspolicy_is_automation_enabled() != 1)
       BEGIN
           RAISERROR(34022, 16, 1)
       END
   ```
2. Evaluate policies. (type PowerShell)

   ```
   dir SQLSERVER:\SQLPolicy\<SERVER>\<INSTANCE>\Policies | where { $_.ScheduleUid -eq "D8E103AA-6886-4913-BB64-2662580C19E8" } |  where { $_.Enabled -eq 1} | where {$_.AutomatedPolicyEvaluationMode -eq 4} | Invoke-PolicyEvaluation -AdHocPolicyEvaluationMode 2 -TargetServerName <SERVER>\<INSTANCE>
   ```

What's running different here?

Thank you very much in advance!

Best regards,
Dex